# Order Activerecord by array values sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ActiveRecord::Relation @formulas with many rows, i want to order and group them by scope with this sequence %w[dre dre_cc cash_flow attachment_table]

```
@formulas = current_user.company.formulas
scopes = %w[dre dre_cc cash_flow attachment_table]
ordered_formulas = ...
```

Comment: Are you using postgres or mysl?

Comment: i'm using postgres

Comment: Can you please mention expected output as well? Question is non expeditionary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby on Rails 7.0 [`in_order_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of) was introduced that can be used like this (assuming that `scope` is the name of to column):

```
scopes = %w[dre dre_cc cash_flow attachment_table]

@formulas = current_user.company.formulas
ordered_formulas = @formulas.in_order_of(:scope, scopes)
```

When you are still on an older version of Rails then you can get the same result by building a complex order statement by yourself:

```
scopes = %w[dre dre_cc cash_flow attachment_table]

@formulas = current_user.company.formulas

order_clause = "CASE  scope "
scopes.each_with_index do |scope, index|
  order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["WHEN ? THEN ? ", scope, index])
end
order_clause << sanitize_sql_array(["ELSE ? END", scopes.length])

ordered_formulas = @formulas.order(order_clause)
```

When you need this behavior more often in your app then it might make sense to create a helper method or `scope` for it.

Comment: and there is an alternative for an older ruby version?

Comment: @Joana I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: it returns undefined method `sanitize_sql_array' for

Comment: `sanitize_sql_array` is only available in the context of ActiveRecord. This code needs to be used in a scope or class method of an ActiveRecord class. or you have to call the `sanitize_sql_array` method on a class, for example like this: `Formula.sanitize_sql_array(...)` (assuming that you have an ActiveRecord model called `Formular`)